# not able to run .rb file in `Sublime Text2`

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

whenever I am trying to save and run a .rb file through the `Sublime Text2`, getting an error:
`Unable to save /usr/Examples/SO.rb` and the below:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'ruby', u'/usr/Examples/SO.rb']]
[dir:  /usr/Examples]
[path: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
[Finished]
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

**EDIT**

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > puts ENV['PATH']
/home/kirti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/home/kirti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/home/kirti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/home/kirti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/home/kirti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/home/kirti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/home/kirti/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/kirti/.rvm/bin
 => nil

kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ which ruby
/home/kirti/.rvm/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Could you try saving it somewhere else? A normal user usually don't have the permission to write under `/usr` path.

Comment: @JunZhou yes, I tried and saved it. But now could not run it as `ctrl + B` getting the error as mentioned in the post.

Comment: Is there a Ruby in any of the paths shown? It's unclear if you've saved the file, and if so, to where.

Comment: @DaveNewton how to check? please help. I am new in Linux. I tried to save file `SO.rb` in the `/usr/Examples` folder. but couldn't save it.

Comment: How about you save it in your home directory? I'm asking if there's a Ruby *executable* in any of those directories, because in one of your comments you said you saved the file.

Comment: @DaveNewton i failed to save it `/usr/Examples`,thus saved it `/media/kirti/FA686DE4686DA05D/Rubyscript/Ruby SO practice examples`. but still getting error when type `ctrl+B`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortkey **Ctrl+B** initiates a build action, which include two steps:

1. Save the file
2. Build it (using `ruby` in this case)

It seems that you have problems in both step:

1. The first problem is that you opened a file of which you have no writing permission. So the first step will fail.

   To solve this, you should either save it elsewhere, or try launching Sublime Text with `sudo`(which I do not recommend, `/usr/` is not a good place for source code).
2. The second problem is that if you are using RVM, you need some more work to make Sublime Text play well with it. And here is the instruction:

   1. First run `which rvm-auto-ruby` in console to make sure you are using RVM, it should output something like:

      `/home/$YOUR_USER_NAME$/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby`
   2. Then use `Preferences > Browse packages` in Menu Bar of Sublime Text to locate your sublime packages.
   3. Find `Ruby/Ruby.sublime-build` under you packages path, replace the following line:

      `"cmd": ["ruby", "$file"],`

      with

      `"cmd": ["/home/$YOUR_USER_NAME$/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby", "$file"],`

   That will do the trick.

Comment: what command I have to enter?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29055/discussion-between-jun-zhou-and-priti)

Comment: To make things easier, instead of doing `which ruby`, just do a `which rvm-auto-ruby`. Then simply copy and paste that in the location explained above.